# How to get option value of only the selected checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to get option value of only selected checkbox, but I am getting value from all the checkboxes.

My HTML code:

```
 <div class= "outer">
    <div class="inner" id="inner">
    <input type="checkbox" name="machine" value="plane">BBQ Sauce<br>
      <select class="weight" name="m2" id="m2">
        <option value="1">Light</option>
        <option value="2">Normal</option>
        <option value="3">Extra</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="inner" id="inner">
    <input type="checkbox" name="machine" value="plane"> Alfredo Sauce<br>
       <select class="weight" name="m2" id="m2">
          <option value="1">Light</option>
          <option value="2">Normal</option>
          <option value="3">Extra</option>
       </select>
    </div>
 </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

My JavaScript code:

```
 function myAction(){
   var vals = [];
   var machine = document.getElementsByName('machine');

   var m2 = document.getElementById('m2');

   for(var i=0, n= machine.length; i<n; i++){
        if(machine[i].checked){
            vals.push(m2.value);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: ID should be unique, the ID of both the `<select>` is same. Same with `#inner`.

Comment: How should I append all the option values of selected checkboxes with ID in an array?

Comment: Just a quick question, can a user theoretically have selected both "1 plane" and "2 planes"? Cause it makes no sense... If I have 2 planes, than logically why would I have to bother with the "1 plane" checkbox?

Comment: @akshaytalathi so? Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I will change it. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique.

Instead, you could use **[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** on the existing `weight` classes to grab only the `select` elements that follow a checked `input` (using the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)):

```
document.querySelectorAll('input:checked ~ .weight')
```

The `select` element values will be the same as their selected options' values.

**Snippet**

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', myAction);

function myAction() {
  var vals = [],  //no need for new Array()
      weights= document.querySelectorAll('input:checked ~ .weight');
  
  for(var i = 0 ; i < weights.length ; i++) {
    vals.push(weights[i].value);
  }
  
  console.log(vals);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" id="inner">
    <input type="checkbox" name="machine" value="plane">I have a plane
    <br>
    <select class="weight" name="m2">
      <option value="1">Light</option>
      <option value="2">Normal</option>
      <option value="3">Extra</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <div class="inner" id="inner">
    <input type="checkbox" name="machine" value="plane">I have 2 planes
    <br>
    <select class="weight" name="m2">
      <option value="1">Light</option>
      <option value="2">Normal</option>
      <option value="3">Extra</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Your suggestion also gives me all the option values of all checkboxes in the vals array. I only want checked checkbox values in the vals array. Thanks

Comment: It prints ["1", "1"] even when I don't select any checkbox and submit. Thanks )

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have m2 repeated twice in your code.  HTML spec specifies undefined behavior when id is repeated (`m2`).   Also your select box isn't a multi-select.  You should just be able to get the value from the select box directly if that is the case.

Comment: How should I append all the option values of selected checkboxes with ID in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` also on nested nodes,
so you could filter the `div.inner` blocks which have the input checked and then get the values from there:

```js
function myAction() {
  //var vals = new Array();
  var inner = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inner'));
  var checked = inner.filter(function(x) {

    var chk = x.querySelector('input');
    if (chk.checked) return x;
  })
  var vals = checked.map(function(x){
    var i = x.querySelector('select').value;
    return i
  });
}
```

BTW as Rick said your markup contain some errors so I would suggest to pass it through a validator_

---

for calling your function on `click` event of the `input` `submit`:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=submit').addEventListener('click', myAction)
```

Comment: Your function is giving me values I require. How can I get those values in vals after submit. Thanks.

Comment: How can I get those values in vals only after submit. Thanks

Comment: Using your function I can get selected values after click, I want them in the vals array only after submit.